# Empty space on right side of page

Tags: html, css

There is some empty space on the right side of a subreddit that I moderate, [r/Fantasy](http://fantasy.reddit.com). The page looks normal on load, but there's a horizontal scrollbar, which if I scroll shows the empty space, with just the background, like so:
[image]

Same issue on mobile. The CSS for the subreddit can be seen [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/about/stylesheet/).

I think the element causing the issue is the div containing the AMA schedule in way down in the sidebar, but can't figure out what's wrong with it.  I'm pretty much dead in the water when it comes to web design/CSS, so any help is appreciated.

And yes, I realise plenty of similar questions exist already, but none of their solutions helped me yet.

Comment: post the link to the website.

Comment: My best bet is it's some element's margin/padding to blame.

Comment: @AmbrishPathak I did, the r/Fantasy is a hyperlink. To be explicit, it's fantasy.reddit.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by the class **.side .md blockquote:nth-of-type(1):after** , 
which is used to create the separator. This has the property display:block and width:400px; which is causing it to overflow. You can change the display type to initial or put a overflow-x hidden on parent element.

you can add the property **overflow-x: hidden** to the class **.side .md blockquote** to get rid of the empty space.

```
.side .md blockquote {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, but can you also explain why it works?

Comment: @hoodakaushal : Explanation added in the answer.